# NodeJS make request synchronized

Tags: node.js

I am receiving a list of video files. For every file received, I extract a thumbnail using [Fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg). The issue I'm facing is that thumbnail extraction is asynchronous and I have to send a response once the extraction is finished. As it is right now, the response is sent even before the first thumbnail was extracted. I know I should use the **async / await** approach but it is unclear how since the function which extracts thumbnails is part of a node_modules package.

```
router.post('/files', function (req, res) {
       let fileList = req.body;
       fileList.forEach(function (file) {
                ffmpeg(file)
                    .on('end', function() {
                        console.log('Screenshots taken');
                    })
                    .screenshots({
                        count: 1,
                        filename: tempFileName + '.png',
                        folder: '/someFolder/'
                    });
        });
        res.send(true);
});
```

Possible workaround I could think of would be to get the length of fileList array, and then in ffmpeg end callback create a counter. If fileList length would be equal to the counter, I could send the response. I don't like this approach and I am sure there is a better one.

It would look something like:

```
router.post('/files', function (req, res) {
       let fileList = req.body;
       let counter = 0;
       fileList.forEach(function (file) {
                ffmpeg(file)
                    .on('end', function() {
                        console.log('Screenshots taken');
                        counter++;
                        if(counter === fileList.length){
                           res.send(true);
                         }
                    })
                    .screenshots({
                        count: 1,
                        filename: tempFileName + '.png',
                        folder: '/someFolder/'
                    });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Leverage the strength of the [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) module by processing every file, and sending a response only when every file has been processed.

```
var async = require('async');

router.post('/files', function (req, res) {
       let fileList = req.body;
       async.each(fileList, function(file, callback){
          ffmpeg(file)
              .on('end', function() {
                  console.log('Screenshots taken');
                  callback();
              })
              .screenshots({
                  count: 1,
                  filename: tempFileName + '.png',
                  folder: '/someFolder/'
              });
       }, function(){
          res.send(true);
       });
});
```

`async.each()` will effectively start each file processing one after the other, without waiting for the previous one to finish. If you want to wait for the processing of a file to finish to start a new one, simply replace `async.each()` with `async.eachSeries()`.

Comment: For some reason, callback() is never called.

Answer (score 0):

If you know async/await, just use it(recommended).

```
router.post('/files', async function(req, res) {
    let fileList = req.body;

    // process in step by step
    for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        let file = fileList[i];
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            ffmpeg(file)
                .on('end', function () {
                    console.log('Screenshots taken');
                    resolve();
                })
                .screenshots({
                    count: 1,
                    filename: tempFileName + '.png', // what is your `tempFileName` ???
                    folder: '/someFolder/'
                });
        });
    }
    // all done!
    res.send(true);

    // process in parallel
    // let promises = fileList.map((file) => {
    //     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //         ffmpeg(file)
    //             .on('end', function () {
    //                 console.log('Screenshots taken');
    //                 resolve();
    //             })
    //             .screenshots({
    //                 count: 1,
    //                 filename: tempFileName + '.png',
    //                 folder: '/someFolder/'
    //             });
    //     });
    // });
    // await Promise.all(promises);
    // // all done!
    // res.send(true);
});
```